# If something has a 1 in X chance of occurring, what are the odds of it actually occurring if I do that thing X times?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Apologies if this is a simple question answered well somewhere else, but I couldn’t find a satisfactory answer in my search.

I was thinking about something that has a 1 in 1000 chance of occurring, for example. If I do that thing 1000 times, it certainly isn’t guaranteed to have happened somewhere among those 1000 attempts. But what are the chances of it having happened somewhere among those tries if I did attempt it 1000 times? Would the answer be “on average, it happens once in every 1000 attempts”? Or is the chance of it happening greater than that? I hope this isn’t too nonsensical. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's $1$ minus the probability that it doesn't happen, which if the probability is $\frac{1}{n}$ and you do $n$ attempts is $1 - \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \approx 1 - e^{-1} \approx 0.632 \dots$. More generally the distribution over the number of successes is approximately Poisson: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Poisson_approximation

Comment: “on average, it happens once in every 1000 attempts” is still the case.  You have a binomial distribution with parameters $X$ and $1/X$, which for large $X$ can be approximated with a Poisson distribution with parameter $1$